# URL with trailing slashes leads to different pages - MVC CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-routing

I have a routed like the following in my Code Igniter route file.

```
$route['profile'] = "profile";
```

The class profile contains the following

```
$this->load->view('pages/profile.php');
```

Now I have a link on my profile.php page which looks like the following

```
<a href = 'logout'>Logout</a>
```

Now consider a user using it. If he visits the following url

```
localhost/project/profile
```

Then now the link on the profile.php page would lead to the following

```
localhost/project/logout
```

But if the user uses this url

```
localhost/project/profile/
```

That is if there is a trailing slash then the link on the page would lead to

```
localhost/project/profile/logout
```

And now my question is what should I do to lead the link in both the cases to

```
localhost/project/logout
```

Hope I am clear. Please help me out

Comment: why don't you use codeingiter url helper?

<a href = '<?=site_url("logout")?>'>Logout</a>

Comment: @FabioAntunes That Helped. Thanks. Any one coming here would find this url helpful - http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you're searching for this, load the url helper on your controller with this code line

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

On your view whenever you want to echo URL's use this code

```
//this will echo something like this http://(yourdomain).index.php/logout
<a href = '<?=site_url("logout")?>'>Logout</a>
```

If you want let's say, an url to another controller you'll use something like this

```
//this will echo something like this http://(yourdomain).index.php/(anothercontroller)/logout
<a href = '<?=site_url("anothercontroller/logout")?>'>Logout</a>
```

More information about the url helper from codeigniter can be found here: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/url_helper.html